# Load karate-config values in gatling simulation

Tags: karate

I am trying to do performance testing and integrate with existing karate project with  gatling plus gradle combination, was able to do the initial setup, but code is not picking up config values written in karate-config file and passing null. My initial simulation code looks like below

class PerfTest extends Simulation{
val getSingleUser = scenario("Login").exec(karateFeature("classpath:Test.feature"))
setUp(
getSingleUser.inject(rampUsers(1).during(1 seconds)))
}

New to both karate and gatling.

I tried using karate protocol() but when i passing protocol in setup  getting below error
There were no requests sent during the simulation, reports won't be generated

Comment: use the sample as a reference: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/examples/gatling - it can be hard. watch out for classpath settings: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#gradle - if still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas I am not able to pass parameters to feature file, i think gradle task is not loading system.properties. really stuck on this. added systemProperties System.properties  in gradle task and also test {
    systemProperty "karate.options", System.properties.getProperty("karate.options")
    systemProperty "karate.env", System.properties.getProperty("karate.env")
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

Comment: if you are stuck, take the time to provide a way to replicate, else no one can help